# How to have multiple OR conditions on a same column

Tags: mysql

I have a column called `price` and I would like to enter a price and get the next most expensive item or if the price entered is beyond the range available in the table the show the most expensive item.

For example I have the following items in my table

```
id  category  price
1    Toys      12
2    Toys      14
3    Toys      18
4    Toys      40
5    Toys      38
6    Toys      67
```

So if I enter 20 I would like the Toy number 5 (price 38) to be returned because that is next big number. If I enter a price that is out of the range of the table for e.g. 100 then I would like the most expensive item to be returned i.e. Toy number 6.

Currently I have a query something like

```
select * 
from items 
where category = ? and price > ? 
order by price limit 1;
```

This returns the next most expensive Toy or any other item of any other category but in case I enter 100 then how would I display the most expensive item? Can I have a multiple `or` on the price column?

**Important**: I would like to achieve this without using coalesce or if null conditions if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select i.* 
from items i
where category = ? 
order by (price > ?) desc,
         (case when price > ? then price end) asc,
         price desc
limit 1;
```

However, a better method (in terms of performance)is probably something like this:

```
(select i.* 
 from items i
 where category = ? and price > ?
 order by price asc
 limit 1
) union all
(select i.*
 from items i
 where category = ?
 order by price desc
 limit 1
)
order by price
limit 1;
```

If the first subquery doesn't return any rows, the second will.  The overhead of sorting two rows is minimal (each subquery as `limit 1`).  And, this should make great use of an index on `items(category, price)` for both subqueries.

Comment: @GrodonLinoff Thank you so much, the first one somehow does not seem to work for me.. Let me try the second one.

Comment: @john.p.doe . . . Note that the number of wildcards has changed.

Comment: Changing the query to this gives me the desired result.. Correct me if I am doing something wrong.
(price > ?) desc, (case when price > ? then price end) asc, price desc limit 1;

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
SELECT i.* 
FROM   items i 
WHERE  category = ?
       AND ( price > ? 
              OR NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                            FROM   items  
                            WHERE  category = ? 
                                   AND price > ?) ) 
    order by (Case when price >? then price else 0-price end)
    limit 1;
```

Comment: I edited the previous answer and it worked for me.. But yours works well as well. Upvoted. Thanks a lot for the effort.